# C++ #include relative path

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, include, relative-path

Is it even possible that relative path is correct, but that I nevertheless get the compilation error:

```
2>src\wfbuilderapp.cpp(15): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: '../project/include/public/core/paths.h': No such file or directory
```

In particular, is it possible that error occurs not because path is wrong, but because the included file "does not permit" that I have this binding between files ? The file where I am including and the included file are located in the same solution, in subfolders of folders located in different projects.

Here are my questions about `#include`:

- Can I include any file as long as path is correct and included file is in the same solution ?
- Can I include .cpp file ?
- Do i sometimes need to include both .cpp and .h files ?

Comment: You can include any file from anywhere as long as the path (relative or absolute) is correct from the current directory. The correctness of what you include is up to you. `#include` is almost like copy pasting your code starting at the location where it is written as `#include` (except for protection against multiple "copy pastes" and some other pragma supports.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I include any file as long as path is correct and included file is in the same solution ?

If the path is correct, yes. It being in the same solution has no effect on the include. The compiler will look for the file in the places it's told to look (adding a file to a solution doesn't modify those places).

The proper way is adding the path to the `Additional Include Directories` in your Project properties.

> Can I include .cpp file ?

Yes, but shouldn't, unless it's for bulk builds.

> Do i sometimes need to include both .cpp and .h files ?

No. You *can*, but don't *need* to. You sometimes *need* to include headers, if the full definition of something defined in the header is needed. As for cpp files, see previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I include any file as long as path is correct

Yes. Note that I snipped the solution part.

> Can I include .cpp file ?

Can, yes. Should? No.

> Do I sometimes need to include both .cpp and .h files

If you "need" to do so, you are using the wrong tool for a problem. cpp files should never be `#include`'ed.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I include any file as long as path is correct and included file is
>   in the same solution ?

You can include any file you like, same solution or not. Whether the compiler can make any sense of it is a different question.

> ```
> Can I include .cpp file ?
> ```

You can but you should not. cpp files should be 'included' in your project, not in other files.

> ```
> Do i sometimes need to include both .cpp and .h files ?
> ```

See answer above. .h files only is the only sensible way to go